# Zooming in macOS iBooks

Tags: macos, books

I am reading an `.ibooks` file which I downloaded from the iBooks Store in the macOS iBooks app. On iOS, to zoom in on the text you can simply double tap or use a pinch gesture. However, it doesn't seem like you can zoom in on an iBook in macOS iBooks with those same gestures on the trackpad. Choosing **Window > Zoom** only affects the size of the window, and unfortunately not the size of the text.

So, is there any way to zoom in on a book in macOS iBooks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not natively supported in the iBook app to zoom or change text size of `.ibooks` files

However I found a way to zoom in. It's maybe not the most elegant solution. But it can be very useful. I also suggest you play with the Zoom settings to get the mode that's best for you.

1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click Accessibility, and then click Zoom.
2. Select “Use keyboard shortcuts to zoom.”
3. - To zoom in use <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>
   - To zoom out use <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

[image: Accessibility > Zoom]

Comment: This iBook doesn't seem to have an option for that. Remember – it's an `.ibook` file, not an `.epub`

Comment: So I've edit my answer. I overlooked the fact that it was an .ibooks file.

Comment: Okay :/ I guess that's how it'll go. I've tried converting the file to a PDF to read it much more easily, but it seems like there aren't any good converters out there. I could take screenshots but that's not elegant IMO